# How to take data from Arduino into an mysql database with an average calculated

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, arduino, average

For my groups final project we are using a Arduino with ph sensor attached. I have the supplied code provided from the ph sensor manufacture which is working great. I have communication from Arduino to java and also displays the information when the code is ran in the output. The mysql statement is correct and all the fields are added. However, when the data from the for loop is written to the database it does something like a sum and creates a large number. I was thinking of using an array list to have the data taken in and then a average performed. Would i need to have the in.read(); assigned to the array?

```
     package Control;

    import Model.fluidTest;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;


  public class ComPortReader {

/**
 *
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
     UnsupportedEncodingException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, 
    IOException {
    //**********************************************************************
    /**
     * These are preparation for the database to be connected and write data
     * to database.
     *
     */
    PreparedStatement reading = null;
    Connection con = null;
    //**********************************************************************
    /**
     * This section of code will be used to take the information from the
     * for loop and place it into a array list to perform the average of the
     * ph input from the Arduino.
     *
     * The input is being added together while uploading to the MYSQL
     * database which is producing incorrect ph level readings.
     */

    // float average 
    //**********************************************************************
    /**
     * This is to open the communication port on the computer to talk to the
     * input device.
     */
    SerialPort comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0];
    comPort.openPort();
    comPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 100, 
    0);
    InputStream in = comPort.getInputStream();  
    try {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        System.out.print((char) in.read());
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
     * This begins the query to the MYSQL database we are connecting to the
     * database using default parameters while using user defined user login
     * and password.
     */




    try {// Try catch to possibly write data to a mysql database.
        con = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phlevel?
    relaxAutoReconnect=false&useSSL=false&relaxAutoCommit=true",

        String sql = "INSERT INTO 
    phlevel.inputreadings(id,phInput,javaReading) values(?,?,?)";
        reading = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        reading.setInt(1, 0); // Creates a new ID Field For performed test.
        reading.setFloat(2, in.read()); 
       // Creates new Float Field for phLevel
        reading.setString(3, "New Reading---->");
       [enter image description here][1]// Creates Label for reading          
        reading.executeUpdate();

        // End MYSQL update QUERY

        con.commit();//End connection to mysql 
        reading.close();// Finish statements to mysql
        comPort.closePort(); // Close the Serial port connected to ardiuno.

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      final int SAMPLE_DATA_COUNT = 100;

      float averagePH = 0;

      for (int j = 0; j < SAMPLE_DATA_COUNT; j++) {
        System.out.print((char) in.read());
        averagePH += Float.parseFloat( in.read() );
      }

      averagePH /= SAMPLE_DATA_COUNT; // Insert this value to SQL
      ...
      reading.setFloat( 2, averagePH );
```

I think this line

```
reading.setInt(1, 0);
```

Should not be there in the first place, the id (Primary Key) column should be set to Auto Increment and you don't need to specify it when inserting data.

Comment: I used your example and it worked very well. I just had to add one more thing to it for it to work.  I was receiving a error. Thanks a bunch to help me lay ground work to find the solution        `averagePH += Float.parseFloat(Integer.toString(in.read()));`